# Find class references in c# source code with roslyn

Tags: c#, reflection, roslyn

I want to find all class references within code. I have looked at Roslyn and its features, but i am kind of in over my head with all of its features. All examples i have seen start off with small code snippets that are being read in, but i would like to just point my code to an assembly let its magic work.

So, given a class structure like this:

```
class MyClassA { }
class MyClassB 
{
   void Do()
   {
      var instance = new MyClassA();      
   }
}
```

All i really want is to find all those dependencies (eg. the "references" feature of Visual Studio, just in code) between `MyClassA` and `MyClassB`. I could either point it to already compiled assemblies, but also point to a proj or sln file.

**Update**

I have looked at a suggestion from comments and have now built something along the lines like this:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
        {
            var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(
                "C:\\src\\mySolution.sln");

            foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
            {
                var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
                foreach (var document in project.Documents)
                {
                    var model = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
                }

                var symbol = compilation.ResolveType("MyClassA").FirstOrDefault();

                if (symbol != null)
                {
                    var references = await SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(symbol, solution);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> ResolveType(this Compilation compilation, string classFullName)
    {
        return new IAssemblySymbol[] { compilation.Assembly }
            .Concat(compilation.References
                .Select(compilation.GetAssemblyOrModuleSymbol)
                .OfType<IAssemblySymbol>())
            .Select(asm => asm.GetTypeByMetadataName(classFullName))
            .Where(cls => cls != null);
    }
```

However, i do not find a single symbol, also none of the projects actually contains a document? What am i doing wrong.

Comment: You'll probably find the method you need in `SymbolFinder`.

Comment: @Luaan Thanks for your suggestion, i have tried my luck with this method, but it seems like i am configuring something wrong.